# I want to know about the multi thread with future on Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala

I know multi thread with future a little such as :

```
for(i <- 1 to 5) yield future {
   println(i)
}
```

but this is all the threads do same work.

So, i want to know how to make two threads which do different work concurrently.

Also, I want to know is there any method to know all the thread is complete?

Please, give me something simple.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, chances are you might be happy with [parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html), especially if all you need is to crunch some data in parallel using multiple threads:

```
val lines = Seq("foo", "bar", "baz")
lines.par.map(line => line.length)
```

While parallel collections suitable for finite datasets, Futures are more oriented towards events-like processing and in fact, future defines task, abstracting away from execution details (one thread, multiple threads, how particular task is pinned to thread) -- all of this is controlled with [execution context](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext). What you can do with futures though is to add callback (on success, on failure, on both), compose it with another future or await for result. All this concepts are nicely explained in [official doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) which is worthwhile reading.